# How to loop table in php

Tags: php, mysql, loops, mysqli

How can I loop this table in PHP?

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM table1";

$select= mysqli_query($connection, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($select);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array("$select")) // line 21
{
    echo $row["column1"];
}
```

I have updated the code and I get this error

> Recoverable fatal error
>   : Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string on line 21

Comment: What's the exact problem with that code, besides it not doing anything but skipping the first row?

Comment: Are you following any tutorial like [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) ?

Comment: I'm new in PHP, studying course lessons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your current code.

1. You fetch the first row with `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($select);` (line 3), but you don't do anything with it. This means that the first result is discarded.
2. Your `while` loop attempts to loop over an incorrect variable (`$query` is a string, not the result-object), and you've quoted it into a string - you need to do it as you were with the first fetch (line 3).
3. You don't do anything inside your loop, so the results aren't printed. At the very least, you should print them with `echo`.

```php
$query = "SELECT * FROM table1";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row["column1"]."<br />\n";
}
```